# Style error // odoo-11 community

Tags: odoo-11

SME Server-9.2 (from Centos-6.10) 64 bits,  virtual with latest VirtualBox.

On july 21st 2018, installation was perfect and everything works perfectly. I did a complete doc of the installation. I used git for the installation.

In august, with a new machine, i tried again with the same doc and I received this error:

```
* * * * * * * * * *

Style error
The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made.

(b'', b'The "--no-js" argument is deprecated, as inline JavaScript is disabled by default. Use "--js" to enable inline JavaScript (not recommended).
[TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'assign']
')This error occured while compiling the bundle 'web.assets_common' containing:
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/variables.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/buttons.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/clearfix.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap/less/mixins/size.less
    - /web/static/src/less/variables.less
    - /web/static/src/less/utils.less
    - /web_editor/static/src/less/web_editor.variables.less
    - /web/static/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/_bootstrap-datetimepicker.less
    - /web/static/src/less/fonts.less
    - /web/static/src/less/navbar.less
    - /web/static/src/less/mimetypes.less
    - /web/static/src/less/modal.less
    - /web/static/src/less/animation.less
    - /web/static/src/less/rainbow.less
    - /web/static/src/less/datepicker.less
    - /web_planner/static/src/less/web_planner_common.less
    - /web_tour/static/src/less/tip.less
    - /web_tour/static/src/less/keyframes.less

* * * * * * * * * *
```

I can update the original July machine and all is OK but impossible to make the new machine working.

I looked in different forums and can not find a solution.

Any help appreciated,

Michel-André

Comment: Check your installation of lessc, which is a nodejs-based program.  The stack trace indicates an issue with nodejs.

Comment: For the other problem, it took me a very long time but I found that it was the latest version of NPM causing the problem with LESSC. I installed Node.js-10.5.0 and all was working properly after that.

Michel-André

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue, I ran below mentioned commands and gets resolved

for MacOs you can execute below mentioned command

`brew uninstall --force node`

`brew install node`

`sudo npm install -g less`

`brew link --overwrite node`

`run odoo with assets`